# Ruby symbol naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently reviewing a clients code base for the company I am interning for. The API is built with Ruby on Rails. I am new to Ruby, but have programmed in other languages, so looking through the code (and some tutorials), I have been able to understand most of what is going on, but there is a line that looks like the code below that is throwing me off. Why do the names of the symbols have equals in front? This feels illegal, but ruby is kinda cool. Thank you for your help.

`delegate :name=, :description=, :tags=, to: :user`

Comment: They're setter methods, nothing more. If you search the web for sthng like "ruby setter methods" you'll find plenty. `delegate` takes symbols representing the methods to delegate. The symbol for a method named `name=` is `:name=`.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another point: In Ruby, as a pattern you don't use the prefixes `set` or `get`, instead you use just the attribute name for the `get` and suffix `=` for the `set`. Example: `setName` and `getName` methods would be `name=` and `name` respectively.

Ruby allows you to use the setter method in these sintaxes: `obj_instance.name = 'Name'` (You can omit the `()` and use space before caracteres like `=`) or `obj_instance.name=('Name')`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

A ruby symbol has very few restrictions concerning the characters it can have, and it's mainly linked to the "easy" representation we usually choose.

It's totally possible to have the following symbols:

```rb
:"hello/world"
:€
:"a+b"
```

It becomes a bit trickier when the symbol is used to represent a method, because we like the easy syntax that comes with it, but it's actually the same as sending the symbol using e.g. `public_send`:

```rb
foo.public_send(:"a+b")
```

This code will work if you define a method named :"a+b". Of course, you can't define it with the usual `def`, but it's still possible.

---

Now, some methods such as `name=` offer an additional semantic, so that the following are equivalent:

```rb
object.name = "Fubar"
object.send(:name=, "Fubar")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: @Praise you're welcome :) And now you can even upvote